# Query category via JSON with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I have this JSON file. I would like to query only the **Post-Game categories**, however, I need the last two of them.

```
    {
    "videos" : [
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSorwgunfqo",
            "category" : "Pre-Game",
            "team" : ["Rodholfo Silva"],
            "date" : "January 20th 2021"
        },
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFzxV0Dc2rw",
            "category" : "Post-Game",
            "team" : ["Rod Patrón"],
            "date" : "January 21st 2021"
        },
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nq0358cJb-M",
            "category" : "Post-Game",
            "team" : ["Rod Patrón"],
            "date" : "January 17th 2021"
        },
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iALl-ce5dzY",
            "category" : "Pre-Game",
            "team" : ["Rodholfo Silva"],
            "date" : "January 16th 2021"
        },
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UY4WvV3dHNY",
            "category" : "Enterviews",
            "team" : ["Mathew Francis, Rodholfo Silva, Rod Patrón"],
            "date" : "July 16th 2020"
        },
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E2hMsmdbd4",
            "category" : "Post-Game",
            "team" : ["Rod Patrón"],
            "date" : "January 24th 2021"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using Javascript, via `for` loops and `slice(1).slice(-2)`, but not success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSorwgunfqo",
            "category" : "Pre-Game",
            "team" : ["Rodholfo Silva"],
            "date" : "January 20th 2021"
        },
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFzxV0Dc2rw",
            "category" : "Post-Game",
            "team" : ["Rod Patrón"],
            "date" : "January 21st 2021"
        },
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nq0358cJb-M",
            "category" : "Post-Game",
            "team" : ["Rod Patrón"],
            "date" : "January 17th 2021"
        },
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iALl-ce5dzY",
            "category" : "Pre-Game",
            "team" : ["Rodholfo Silva"],
            "date" : "January 16th 2021"
        },
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UY4WvV3dHNY",
            "category" : "Enterviews",
            "team" : ["Mathew Francis, Rodholfo Silva, Rod Patrón"],
            "date" : "July 16th 2020"
        },
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E2hMsmdbd4",
            "category" : "Post-Game",
            "team" : ["Rod Patrón"],
            "date" : "January 24th 2021"
        }
    ];

const postGames = data.filter(({ category }) => category === "Post-Game").slice(-2);
console.log(postGames);

/*

const postGames = data
    .filter(({ category }) => category === "Post-Game")
    .filter(({ date }) => //put your condition here)
    .slice(-2);
console.log(postGames);

const postGamesByDatet = data
    .filter(({category, date }) => category === "Post-Game" && date_is_after(date))
    .slice(-2);
*/
```

Comment: Awesome. Is that also possible to "mix" the filter and sort it by date?

Comment: you can sort it by date by chaining [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function to it before `slice` if you want to sort the result before get the last 2 items or after `slice` if you want to sort the final result, same for the filtering, if you want to filter all postGame  by date for example after `January 20th` you just need to add it to the condition . What do you mean by "mix" of filter

Comment: Mix  I mean, it is like, adding more than one filter.

Comment: yes, without any problem, you can stack the function by chaining it or add your new condition inside the filter, i've updated my response

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file content is contained in the `records` variable and your wanted records called `result`:

```
const result = records.videos.filter(video => video.category === 'Post-Game').slice(-2);
```

Comment: Awesome. Is that also possible to "mix" the filter and sort it by date?